# NOSQL "basic operations"

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql

If I wanted to define a minimum set of functionality for an investigative NOSQL implementation, which ones should I pick?

I like the Google AppEngine API and its simple methods (e.g. Get all objects of type X, get all objects with property Y, etc.) but I wonder whether there is a base layer of calls that can be considered "expected of all similar systems", a sort of (portable?) baseline API for NOSQL?

Is there an instructive FOSS minimalistic implementation of such simple system? I would like to study it and see how it creates indices, allocates storage blocks, performs queries, distributes saves, etc.

This is for educational and research purposes.

Comment: I suppose you need to define what you think are " similar systems".  The wikipedia article lists a lot of very different nosql systems.  Maybe you should focus on a subset NOSQL flavours based on the taxonomy provided in the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL . Some systems are just key value stores.  Others like RDF / triple stores don't have a key as such, but are based on queries on  subject-predicate-object combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an enormous breadth of 'NoSQL' systems out there, and many of them have very little in common except the label of 'NoSQL' and the most basic of operations: insert, update/replace and delete. Pretty much every other attribute of a storage system - indexing, datatypes, data structure, allowable queries, and so forth - varies wildly from database to database.

It may be that over time standards emerge, but for now about the only thing you can be sure of about a NoSQL database is that it'll be capable of storing data and retrieving it again.